# Unable to invoke web service with security

Tags: java, jax-ws, cxf, mule, ws-security

I have crated a CXF JAXWS Service as below.

I have provided a custom UserNameToken validator and a callback handler.

But this is not working. It throws an error everytime.

```
<http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/HelloService"  exchange-pattern="request-response">
    <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.example.service.HelloServiceImpl" >
    <cxf:ws-security>
    <cxf:ws-config>                     
    <cxf:property key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
    </cxf:ws-config>
    <cxf:ws-custom-validator >                  
        <cxf:username-token-validator ref="customUsernameTokenValidator" />
    </cxf:ws-custom-validator>                  
      </cxf:ws-security> 
     <cxf:properties>
            <spring:entry key="ws-security.ut.validator" value-ref="customUsernameTokenValidator" ></spring:entry>
            <spring:entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value-ref="myPasswordCallback" ></spring:entry>
        </cxf:properties>
        .....
        .....
```

And a policy on my WSDL binding as below

```
        <sp:SupportingTokens> 
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                    <wsp:Policy />
                </sp:UsernameToken>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:SupportingTokens>
```

I get the below error when I fire my request from SOAPUI with usernametoken and password.

```
2013-04-10 11:08:13,811 WARN  [qtp1221956599-40 - /HelloService] logging.LogUtils (LogUtils.java:384) - Interceptor for {http://example.org/HelloService}ProductSOAPService#{http://example.org/HelloService}addCompany has thrown exception, unwinding now
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
        at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker.invoke(MuleInvoker.java:106)
        at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleJAXWSInvoker.invoke(MuleJAXWSInvoker.java:47)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
        .....
        .....
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.mule.module.cxf.MuleInvoker.invoke(MuleInvoker.java:60)
        ... 29 more
```

Please help me understand what I missing here.

Note: I have tried the Mule way of implementing the security on jaxws using cxf:ws-security and my service is  working and giving proper response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cxf jaxws-service should be as below. Then it should work.

```
<http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/HelloService"  exchange-pattern="request-response">
<cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.example.service.HelloServiceImpl" >
 <cxf:properties>
        <spring:entry key="ws-security.ut.validator" value-ref="customUsernameTokenValidator" ></spring:entry>
        <spring:entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value-ref="myPasswordCallback" ></spring:entry>
    </cxf:properties>
  </cxf:jaxws-service>
```